# Vector Space as Subspace of Tensor product

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

The question I am interested in is the following:

> Is there any "natural" way in which $V$ can be regarded as a subspace of $V\otimes W$ ($V$,$W$ vector spaces)?

My attempt at an answer is the following: It is known that for finite dimensional vector spaces $V\otimes W \simeq \text{Hom}(V^*;W)$. It seems I am asked to construct a "natural" monomorphism $\tau: V \to \text{Hom}(V^*;W)$. Given the data, the only thing I am able to construct is the following:
$$
\tau: v \mapsto \Phi_v\in \text{Hom}(V^*;W)
$$
with $\Phi_v(f):=f(v)w$, for all $f\in V^*$ and $w\in W$. In my construction I was "forced" to introduce an arbitrary $w\in W$. Can I conclude that there is no "natural" way in which $V$ can be construed as a subspace of $V\otimes W$? I would like a refinement of the last argument, if prior to that what I tried was correct.

Comment: Well, in general there exists no such monomorphism at all, if $W$ may be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to formalize the question, I think what you want to know is: is there any natural transformation $\eta$ between the functors $Vect_k \times Vect_k \to Vect_k$, $(V, W) \mapsto V$ and $(V, W) \mapsto V \otimes_k W$, such that $\eta_{(V, W)}$ is injective for all $V, W$?

In fact, the only such natural transformation is the zero map.  To see this, try applying the naturality constraint on $(\operatorname{id}_V, 0) : (V, W) \to (V, W)$ and see what you get.